# Sprite Kit NSArray of multiple sprites?

Tags: nsmutablearray, sprite-kit, sprite

I have 6 sprite images I am trying to add to my scene, adding each of them seems to slow everything down a lot. I figured I would need to create an NSArray in order to help with speed. Here is the array I've created, but it's only adding the first image, how can I get it to add all 6?? Thank you in advance!

**myArray**

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1",@"image2",@"image3",@"image4",@"image5",@"image6", nil];

NSInteger count = [myArray count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (i > 5) {
        break;
    }
    result = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
}

//Setting SKSpriteNodes from array.
dice = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[myArray objectAtIndex:result.intValue]];
```

Comment: What makes you think a NSMutableArray would help the performance of rendering ?

Comment: ..or improve creating/initializing/adding the sprites and texture loading?

Comment: @prototypical So what would help in this case?

Comment: For someone to answer that question, they would need to see your code and/or know more about what you are doing. How many nodes ? How many draws ? Are you having framerate issues in the simulator or on the device ?  Take some time to troubleshoot and check out some of the other questions on this site related to performance.

Comment: I think @LearnCocos2D is likely right that your issue potentially revolves around texture loading, and you should take the time to learn about preloading textures, fonts, and audio.

Comment: It says 6 sprites in the first sentence. This is a general question, best way to do it.

Comment: I've changed the code showing an array, I can only get the first image to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a property in you scene:

```
@interface MyScene
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
@end
```

Then create a method to fill that array:

```
- (void)fillItems {

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *d1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Sprite1"];

    d1.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/4 + arc4random() % ((int)self.frame.size.width/2),
                              self.frame.size.height/2 + arc4random() % ((int)self.frame.size.height/2));

    d1.color = [self randomColor];
    d1.colorBlendFactor = 1.0;
    d1.xScale = 0.25;
    d1.yScale = 0.25;
    d1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:d1.frame.size];

    //Adding SpriteKit physicsBody for collision detection
    d1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = diceCategory;
    d1.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    d1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = frameCategory;
    d1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = diceCategory | frameCategory;
    d1.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    d1.name = @"Sprite1";
    [self.items addObject:d1];
    [self addChild:d1];
}
```

Comment: Congradulations, you've found an answer to your question

Comment: Thank you, do you know why only 1 sprite shows up and not all 6?

Comment: do you know why only 1 sprite shows up and not all 6?

Comment: can you tell me why it's only adding the first sprite?